# Kazam + Pavucontrol problems

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, screencasting

I installed Kazam in order to record my screen. The video capture was fine, but the audio quality was bad. So I bought a better microphone.

The new microphone, while much better for using with other programs (like Audacity) has a USB input instead of 3.5 mm, and some programs like Firefox and, yes, Kazam, did not recognize it. So I had to install Pulseaudio volume control and configure it so that my new microphone is used to record audio for each application.

Now Firefox recognizes my microphone, as do Audacity and Skype, but Kazam has an even bigger problem: every time I try to stop recording, it freezes! So I cannot, in fact, record anything at all. I tried reinstalling Kazam. It did not help.

I tried running Kazam in debug mode and got the following output:

---

```
DEBUG Kazam - Starting ...
DEBUG Kazam - Running on: debian 8.7
DEBUG Kazam - Kazam version: 1.4.5 NCC-80102
DEBUG Kazam - Starting new instance ...
DEBUG Prefs - XDG_PICTURES is a directory and accessible
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Getting hardware specs
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Getting Video sources.
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Found 1 monitor(s).
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Monitor 0 - X: 0, Y: 0, W: 1280, H: 720
DEBUG Main - Gstreamer version detected: 1.4.4.0
DEBUG Main - Setting variables.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Starting mainloop.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Getting API.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Setting context.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Set state callback.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Connecting to server.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Start mainloop.
DEBUG PulseAudio - State connected.
DEBUG Main - Connecting indicator signals.
DEBUG Main - Starting in silent mode: False
DEBUG Indicator - Indicatior silent: False
DEBUG Indicator - Trying to bind hotkeys.
DEBUG Main - Main Window UI setup.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py:145: Warning: value "((GtkIconSize) 32)" of type 'GtkIconSize' is invalid or out of range for property 'icon-size' of type 'GtkIconSize'
self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(prefs.data dir, "ui", "kazam.ui"))
DEBUG Main - Unable to get name for '<Adjustment object at 0x7f425f232318 (GtkAdjustment at 0x2d62200)>'

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screencast-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screenshot-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent


(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-fullscreen-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-all-screens-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-window-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-area-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:12111): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent

DEBUG Prefs - Getting Audio sources.
DEBUG PulseAudio - get_audio_sources() called.
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio - IDX: 0
DEBUG PulseAudio - Name: b'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor'
DEBUG PulseAudio - Desc: b'Monitor of Audio Interno Est\xc3\xa9reo Anal\xc3\xb3gico'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio - IDX: 1
DEBUG PulseAudio - Name: b'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo'
DEBUG PulseAudio - Desc: b'Audio Interno Est\xc3\xa9reo Anal\xc3\xb3gico'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio - IDX: 8
DEBUG PulseAudio - Name: b'alsa_output.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo.monitor'
DEBUG PulseAudio - Desc: b'Monitor of ATR USB microphone Est\xc3\xa9reo Anal\xc3\xb3gico'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio - IDX: 9
DEBUG PulseAudio - Name: b'alsa_input.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo'
DEBUG PulseAudio - Desc: b'ATR USB microphone Est\xc3\xa9reo Anal\xc3\xb3gico'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb() -- finished
DEBUG Prefs - Device found:
DEBUG Prefs - - 0
DEBUG Prefs - - alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
DEBUG Prefs - - Monitor of Audio Interno Estéreo Analógico
DEBUG Prefs - Device found:
DEBUG Prefs - - 1
DEBUG Prefs - - alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
DEBUG Prefs - - Audio Interno Estéreo Analógico
DEBUG Prefs - Device found:
DEBUG Prefs - - 8
DEBUG Prefs - - alsa_output.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo.monitor
DEBUG Prefs - - Monitor of ATR USB microphone Estéreo Analógico
DEBUG Prefs - Device found:
DEBUG Prefs - - 9
DEBUG Prefs - - alsa_input.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo
DEBUG Prefs - - ATR USB microphone Estéreo Analógico
DEBUG Main - Capture speakers: True.
DEBUG Main - Capture microphone: True.
DEBUG Main - Capture cursor_pic: True.
DEBUG Main - Capture borders_pic: True.
DEBUG Main - Start delay now: 3
DEBUG Main - Record clicked, invoking Screencast.
DEBUG GStreamer - Audio_source : alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
DEBUG GStreamer - Audio2_source : alsa_input.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo
DEBUG GStreamer - Video_source: {'height': 720, 'x': 0, 'width': 1280, 'y': 0}
DEBUG GStreamer - Xid: None
DEBUG GStreamer - Area: None
DEBUG GStreamer - Capture Cursor: False
DEBUG GStreamer - Framerate : 15.0
DEBUG GStreamer - Coordinates SX: 0 SY: 0 EX: 1279 EY: 719
DEBUG GStreamer - testing for xid: None
DEBUG GStreamer - Codec: H264 (MP4)
DEBUG GStreamer - Setup audio elements.
DEBUG GStreamer - Audio1 Source:
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
DEBUG GStreamer - Audio2 Source:
alsa_input.usb-Audio-Technica_ATR_USB_microphone-00-microphone.analog-stereo
DEBUG GStreamer - Filesink: /home/gabi/Vídeos/kazam_jmxt5pgq.movie
DEBUG GStreamer - Linking Video
DEBUG GStreamer - Linking Audio
DEBUG GStreamer - Link audiosrc -> aud_in_queue: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link aud_in_queue -> aud_caps_filter: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Linking Audio2
DEBUG GStreamer - Link aud_caps_filter -> audiomixer: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link audio2src -> aud2_in_queue: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link aud2_in_queue -> aud2_caps_filter: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link aud2_caps_filter -> audiomixer: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link audiomixer -> audioconv: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link audioconv -> audioenc: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link audioenc -> aud_out_queue: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link aud_out_queue -> mux: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link mux -> file queue: True
DEBUG GStreamer - Link file queue -> sink: True
DEBUG Main - Hiding main window.
DEBUG Main - Counter finished.
DEBUG Indicator - Recording started.
DEBUG GStreamer - Setting STATE_PLAYING
DEBUG Indicator - Recording stopped.
DEBUG Main - Stop request.
DEBUG GStreamer - Sending new EOS event
```

---

At that point, it freezes and does nothing else. It never shows me the options window again, and I can't even close it unless I kill the process.

If I set up Pulseaudio Volume Control to use the monitor of the device rather than the device itself, then I can stop recording and save a file, but I cannot reproduce it. All I get is one second of silence, with no video, and Kazam cannot delete the temporary 0-byte .movie file.